# dbms_output.put_line() is getting commented and not printing anything in the output except "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed"

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsql-package

When I am using dbms_output.put_line() in any of of Pl/SQL program, this line is not getting printed and it is not showing any kind of error message, whenever I am running my program is is just printing "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed".

For an example When I am running the following piece of code it is showing the similar behaviour and not printing anything.

```
DECLARE 
   message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!'; 
BEGIN 
   dbms_output.put_line(message); 
END;
```

When I am running the above code, the output is the following:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Moreover on my worksheet screen the `dbms_output.put_line()` is showing in colors like it is commented out. Although I have checked many times nothing is commented.

Comment: Are you using Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: Yes it is Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Corrected tag. [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqldeveloper-landing.html) and [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) are two different products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to set serveroutput on.  View/DBMS output/pick the connection to show the output window.
In SQL Plus:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
```

Comment: Thank You very much, running this command at the top of the program worked. Thank you again

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using SQL Developer make sure to follow the steps:

1. Go to **View**
2. Click on **Dbms Output** (this will create a window on SQL Developer)
3. Click the **+** button, this will create a prompt.
4. Select the connection, the selected connection will appear and the background of Dbms Output will turn white
5. Run the procedure.